# SharePoint Online multi-tenant REST calls return 404 on resources that definitely exist

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to access the SharePoint Online REST API (this is hand coded REST calls, no library being used).

Access tokens are acquired using authorization grant flow as follows:

1. I send the browser https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?...
2. This redirects to a handler endpoint that we extract the access code from
3. I obtain the tenant ID by:
   GET https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc
   Then extracting the tenant ID from the WWW-Authenticate header
4. I then POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/authorize) to obtain the access token

When I use that access token, I am able to do queries using:
GET https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=....

This works and returns documents.

But when I attempt to retrieve information about one of those documents:
GET https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/TestFiles/test.pdf')

I get a 404 response with the following body:

{"odata.error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file /TestFiles/test.pdf does not exist."}}}

If I navigate to the URL in a browser (https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/TestFiles/test.pdf), it accesses the file without issue.

This makes me think that I'm running into some sort of permission issue.

I have tried setting the following scopes in the authorize redirect:

Attempt 1: scope = Web.Write AllSites.Write Site.Write
Attempt 2: scope = https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/.default
Attempt 3: scope = https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/Web.Write https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/AllSites.Write https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/Site.Write

No matter what I set as the scope parameter of the authorize URL, the JWT details of the access token show (I can post the entire decoded JWT if anyone needs it):

"scp": "User.Read"

Nothing I do has any impact on the scp in the token - I have no idea if that's the issue or not.  If it is, I would appreciate hearing how to properly request scope.

The application registration in Azure Active Directory has desired permissions (plus more):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE: Switching to OAuth endpoint v2.0:**

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

With query parameters:
response_type = code
client_id = my app id
redirect_uri = my redirect uri
scope = <varying - I'll explain what happens under different scenarios below>

Here's what I've tried for scopes:

**AllSites.Write Site.Write** - the redirect has invalid_client with error_description = AADSTS650053: The application '' asked for scope 'AllSites.Write' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor.

**https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/AllSites.Write https://.sharepoint.com/Site.Write** - the redirect has invalid_client with error description = AADSTS650053: The application '' asked for scope 'Site.Write' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor.

**https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/.default** - this goes through

- But the resulting JWT has only scp=User.Read
- The following works:  GET https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=
- But the following returns a 404:  GET https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/TestFiles/test.pdf')

I don't understand how Scope=.Default isn't including the allowed permissions from the application registration.  And I definitely don't understand why the AllSites.Write scope is failing when it's explicitly specified.

If it helps, I have also tried all of the above using a tenant specific authorize endpoint instead of 'common':
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)

---

**UPDATE2: More scope changes:**

I finally found a magical combination that works:

Use a tenant based URI for the /authorize *and* /token endpoint and use {tenanturl}\AllSites.Write for the scope (do NOT specify the Site.Write scope):

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri={redirecturi}&scope=https%3A%2F%2F{tenantname}.sharepoint.com%2FAllSites.Write](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclientid%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirecturi%7D&scope=https%3A%2F%2F%7Btenantname%7D.sharepoint.com%2FAllSites.Write)

The resulting JWT has the following:
"scp": "AllSites.Write User.Read"

I am completely perplexed about why Site.Write wasn't allowed.  I suppose that AllSites.Write is a superset of Site.Write, so maybe not needed?

All of my testing so far has been on my own tenant, next step is to test on a different tenant and make sure it actually works there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use v1.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` but not v2.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. If we use v1.0 endpoint, we should use `resource` instead of `scope`. So that is why the `scp` claim in your access token always the same no matter you modify the `scope`.

You should use `resource` with `https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com` and the parameter `scope` is useless when you use v1.0 endpoint.

If you still want to use `scope` parameter, you can also change the endpoint to v2.0. Just add `v2.0` into your endpoint, like: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Comment: Thanks - this was a big help.  I switched to the V2.0 endpoint which got me actual error messages.  Please see my updates above - still doesn't make any sense that we can't specify multiple scopes...

Comment: Hi @KevinDay I test it in my side, it works fine. I use `https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/.default` as scope parameter. Could you please do "Grant admin consent for xxx" for the permissions in your registered app and use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` when you acquire the access token. This is all the difference between my steps and yours.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I can't grant admin consent (that's not part of our use-case).  And we do use /token for obtaining the token.  Maybe the problem is that this is a multi-tenant application (not sure if /.default even works across tenants).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a magical combination that works:

1. use the [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) and [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) endpoints
2. specify {tenanturl}\AllSites.Write for the scope (do NOT specify the Site.Write scope - that was the primary problem):

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri={redirecturi}&scope=https%3A%2F%2F{tenantname}.sharepoint.com%2FAllSites.Write](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclientid%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirecturi%7D&scope=https%3A%2F%2F%7Btenantname%7D.sharepoint.com%2FAllSites.Write)

The resulting JWT has the following: "scp": "AllSites.Write User.Read"

This works across tenants and gets us the access we need.

For thoroughness, we also specify offline_access scope so we get a refresh_token in addition to the access_token.